# fork with map function in Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I am a beginner at **redux-sagas** and I am confused with the following situation. I have an items array and I want to fork the same method for each item. So I am using this line of code:

```
yield items.map(item => fork(loadItemDetails, item));
```

With the above-mentioned code, `loadItemDetails` is never invoked. On the contrary, if I call `fork` individually on each item, as shown below, then it works as intended.

```
yield fork(loadItemDetails, items[0]);
yield fork(loadItemDetails, items[1]);
yield fork(loadItemDetails, items[2]);
```

This is confusing me and I can't figure out the reason why the map won't work.

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same issue.

```
items.forEach(item => yield fork(loadItemDetails, item));
```

won't work, as you will get the following error:

> A 'yield' expression is only allowed in a generator body.

In order to resolve it, I used `yield all`

```
export function* itemDetailsSage() {
  const { items } = yield take(SET_CART_ITEMS);
  yield all(items.map(item => fork(loadItemDetails, item)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little late but this should work.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    yield fork(loadItemDetails, items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add `yield` inside of the loop before the `fork()` and instead of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) then it should work like the other example what you have with separated `fork` calls.

Try the following:

```
items.forEach(item => yield fork(loadItemDetails, item));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about using a`for of`:

```js
for (let item of items) {
    yield fork(loadItemDetails, item);
}
```